# Question about Covariant Derivatives in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, vector-fields

I'm following the differential approach of Schutz' book where vectores are geometrical objects written as

\begin{equation}
\vec{V}=V^a\ \vec{E}_a
\end{equation}

Where $V^a$ are the components of the vector and $\vec{E}_a$ are the vectors of the basis. In this notation,v the covariant derivative of a vector is

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\vec{E}_a}\vec{V}=\nabla_{\vec{E}_a}(V^b)\vec{E}_b+V^b\nabla_{\vec{E}_a}(\vec{E}_b)= \vec{E}_a(V^b)\vec{E}_b+V^b\Gamma^c_{ba}\vec{E}_c
\end{equation}

where vectors are derivatives so $\vec{E}_a(f)$ is the derivative of f along the $a$ vector of the basis. I'm having trouble understanding how to do this calculation

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\vec{E}_a}\nabla_{\vec{E}_b} f= \nabla_{\vec{E}_a}\big[\vec{E}_b(f) \big]
\end{equation}

On one hand, $\vec{E}_b(f)$ is just a real number so de covariant derivative should just apply the normal derivation. On the other hand, it has an index $b$ so it transforms non-trivially, so I think that maybe we should apply the covariant derivative as if it was a tensor...

That is the main question, how do we apply the covariant derivative to something like $\vec{E}_b(f)$?

Comment: Here $b$ is just the label index for the basis vector, not an index of a component of a tensor. In your case $\vec{E}_b(f)$ is a function so $\nabla_{\vec{E}_a}\vec{E}_b(f)=\vec{E}_a(\vec{E}_b(f))$ .